# JavaFX Ant Build Script in Netbeans: How to improve build speed?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, javafx

Building a JavaFX project from a directory on a networked drive is surprisingly slow. I believe most of the delay is caused by the build script deleting and re-creating the entire /lib directory. This includes over 20 MB of jar files that remain unchanged for my project.

How to I modify the ANT build task so that this lib folder does not get re-created every time I build the project? What else can be done to reduce the build time?

Another reason for the slow build time over my network is that the project always gets run from the /dist folder. For a standard Java SE project, a project can run from the build directory, removing the need to create a new jar file in /dist every time the project runs.

Is there a way to run the project from the .class files in the build directory instead of needing to run from /dist ?

Here are the netbeans generated build files:

- [jfx-impl.xml](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87404450/jfx-impl.xml)
- [build-impl](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87404450/build-impl.xml)

Comment: are these windows workstations? or some flavor of unix?

Answer (score 5):

It would be helpful to see more of your build file, it is possible that the target dependency graph of whatever target your running could be changed.  Put another way, **make a target that doesn't delete** `lib/`

A much larger and cooler solution would be to use [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to download these libs one time to `~/.ivy` where they'd be cached and wouldn't need to be fetched every time you checked out.  This would allow you to shed those binaries from source control.

What reasons prevent you from building locally?

Comment: In the computer lab where I teach, the network policy dictates that no data is stored locally. All of my work and all of my students' work is stored on a networked drive.  My build file is just the default that netbeans 7.3.1 provides for javafx projects. Is it easy to configure Ivy to work with this setup?

Comment: What a useful policy.  Truely Mordac the preventer from Dilbert works at your school.  Does the policy mean all data on the machine is transient and could be deleted at anytime? or that you literally can't store anything locally?  Can you paste in the build.xml or upload it somehere and post the link?  I'm sure we can square something for you.   Ivy should be straightforward - never used netbeans, but it appears to have integration built in.

Comment: +1 for the Dilbert reference :)  I added links to the build files.Thank you for looking into this!

Answer (score 2):

**The suggestions below are only suggested for your development work based upon your description of slow build speeds in your environment.  In general, if NetBeans JavaFX project development builds are already quick enough, the settings above should not be used.  For packaging production applications you will want to use different settings.**

*How to get a quick build for JavaFX under NetBeans*

1. Invest in a solid state drive.
2. Follow thekbb's suggestion of having the library files local to your machine.
3. Use NetBeans 7.4 + Java 8 and create a standard Java project rather than a JavaFX project.
4. Under Project Properties | Libraries uncheck:

   - Build projects on Classpath
5. Under Project Properties | Build | Packaging uncheck:

   - Compress JAR file
   - Build JAR after Compiling
   - Copy Dependent Libraries
6. Under Project Properties | Build | Deployment uncheck:

   - Enable Native Packaging Options in Project Menu
   - Keep JavaFX RT Artifacts on Compile Classpath if not present by default.
7. Under Project Properties | Application | Web Start uncheck:

   - Enable Web Start

If you end up being unable to solve your build performance issues using NetBeans, you might want to try Intellij Idea (I have found it quite efficient at building JavaFX projects).

*My Build Experiences with NetBeans*

A standard NetBeans JavaFX project builds and runs JavaFX projects very quickly for me (no more than a second or two).  That is even without applying most of the build speed suggestions above.  Projects which build in seconds reference over 75 libraries totaling more than 55MB of data.  However, that build timing is when using local libraries, not when using libraries stored on a network.  Also the quick builds are using a Macbook Air (which has an SSD).

If a project is signed, the signing process takes a few seconds per library jar.

Comment: I'm going to try some of these ideas. At home I have a solid state drive and no complaints about build times. In the computer lab where I teach, we are forced to work off of a network drive, so reducing the amount of data that needs to get copied accross the network should help.

Comment: I reference local libraries totaling approximately 85 MB of data. It takes about 15 seconds to deploy. It's quite a nuisance when I'm testing and every small change I make to the code requires me to wait this long before being able to test my app. I have implemented the suggestions above which are relevant (my libraries folder has "build required projects" checkbox, but there are not projects in my libraries anyway). Do you have any more/updated suggestions?

Comment: This question is very old, I would be surprised if much of the answer is still relevant.   I would suggest moving to another IDE (e.g. [IntelliJ Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)), a new build system (e.g. [Maven](https://maven.apache.org)), and to utilize the [openjfx maven plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) as documented at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven).