# Running javafx app with hibernate takes too much time

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I am working on javafx 2.0 using netbeans 7.4 and hibernate..

the issue was that i am run application its build all jar and take too much time to run..

how can i get run fast...

[image]

```
 SessionFactory sess = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session ses = sess.openSession();

         Query qry = ses.createQuery("select count(*) from UserDo");
         Iterator it  =qry.iterate();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*NetBeans build time improvement suggestions*

It seems that likely your issue is not the time taken to run the application, but more the time taken to build it using your current build settings in NetBeans.

Here are some suggestions you can try out which will improve build speed under NetBeans:

[JavaFX Ant Build Script in Netbeans: How to improve build speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137622/javafx-ant-build-script-in-netbeans-how-to-improve-build-speed)

*Background on when you need to sign applications*

From Jitendra's answer, which you marked correct, it seems that your main issue is that you are requesting NetBeans to sign all of your jar files.

Unless you will be deploying your application as a browser embedded application or WebStart application, you don't need to sign the application.

Even if you are going to eventually deploy your application using either of those two modes, you can do all of your development of the application as a standalone application (which does not require signing), and just sign the application when you are ready to deliver it.

*How to disable signing in NetBeans*

Under NetBeans 7.4, to prevent the NetBeans from signing all of your application's jar files, choose:

```
Project Properties | Build | Deployment
```

And make sure the following setting is NOT checked:

```
Request unrestricted access (Enable signing)
```

Comment: @jewelsea Thank You! Its actually miss understanding. Thank you so much. I m suffered by this issue from a long.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is some licensing issues, whenever you run Javafx APP Java Environment check your licensing, if you have default jar then Netbeans show warning messages to avail you for the licensing issues. That's why it seems slow than other apps. Try to communicate with Oracle Support it definitely give you better solution.

The below screen shot you will confirm every jar want a licensing key :

[image]

Comment: What licensing does it check?  I've never seen anything like that for a JavaFX application?  Do you see something visible?  If so, can you describe or include a picture or text of what you see?

Comment: @jewelsea Please see the below Answer. Thanks

Comment: That's not a licensing key. That's occurring because you asked NetBeans to generate a signing certificate and sign all of the jars in the project.  You don't need to do that.  I'll post an answer.

Comment: @jewelsea but i am not till getting my question answer... whenever i run its take to much time,builds all jar.how can do it fast ?? can i change my platform ?? use some another software ??