# Javafx Create custom multilabel button

Tags: javafx

How can I create a custom button in javafx. The button must have  3 label. An Upper Label a center LAbel and a lower label

Comment: did you try with html text within `setText` method. I'm just guessing...:)

Answer (score 1):

```
Button button = new Button();
VBox threeLabels = new VBox();
threeLabels.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
threeLabels.getChildren.setAll(
  new Label("upper"),
  new Label("center"),
  new Label("lower")
);
button.setGraphic(threeLabels);
```

Comment: jewelsea can you help me ?? ... pls give me some suggestion for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969567/running-javafx-app-with-hibernate-takes-too-much-time